# Convert HTML to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Suppose that I have the PHP code as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Convert HTML to PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm" method=post>
 <div class="HoldPage">
 <div class="page">
 <h1 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px;">COMPORTEMENT/COMPETENCES</h1>
 <p style="text-align:center;">Déterminer et évaluer les seuls critères nécessaires à la tenue du poste</p>
 <p class="text_P">COMPETENCES OPERATIONNELLES</p>
 <hr class='dashes'>
 <ul type="disc">
    <li><strong>CONNAISSANCE ET EXPERIENCE (O/E/AM/Cadres)</strong></li>
 </ul>
<input type="submit" name="convert2PDF" value="GeneratePDF">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['convert2PDF'])){
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2pdf.pdf");
    }
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**I need:**

When I click on button submit it will generate HTML to PDF file.

**Problem:**

Actually, It not works.How do I fix this.Does it have any method that easier than this?Anyone help me please.Thanks,

Comment: This works fine for me, but you couldn't open the generated "pdf" file because it's still the html.

Comment: It's not that simple for this. A good google can help you, such as [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: also - sending headers AFTER you output data is never a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tcPDF or dompdf type plugin/extension with cakePHP

review the below link
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf
http://www.juliaholland.org/2009/01/23/cakephp-and-tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

You are not really converting anything, all you are doing is changing the file extension and mime type.
Checkout dompdf, its a class for php which does what you intend.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.